# Why protocol type never gets a value?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to understand more protocols. I could not figure out myProtocolFunction never call and print or passing the variable as below.

I think my problem is about initialization. When I try with two viewcontroller everything is okay but MyStruct protocol instance is nil. Thanks for your help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var myProtocolValue: String = ""
    
    var globalInstance = "a"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        
        var myStruct = MyStruct()
        myStruct.myProtocol = self        
    }
    

    func myProtocolFunction(passing: String) {
        globalInstance = passing
        print("never print")
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolFunction(passing: String)
}


struct MyStruct {

    var myProtocol: MyProtocol?
    
    init() {
        makeSomething()
    }
    
    func makeSomething() {
        myProtocol?.myProtocolFunction(passing: "abc")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: add this line code in class.   ```var myStruct = MyStruct()``` put out from function and add in class body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to make

```
var myStruct = MyStruct() // an instance variable 

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    
    myStruct.myProtocol = self        
}
```

2- Also you call `init` before even you set `myProtocol` as its called when you do `var myStruct = MyStruct()` and at that time `myProtocol` is nil as its not yet set

```
init() {
    makeSomething()
}
```

**Check full working edit**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }
    
    func myProtocolFunction(passing: String) {
        print(passing)
    }
     
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
          
        var myStruct = MyStruct(self)
        
    }
     
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolFunction(passing: String)
}

struct MyStruct {

    var myProtocol: MyProtocol?
    
    init(_ mine:MyProtocol) {
        myProtocol = mine
        makeSomething()
    }
    
    func makeSomething() {
        myProtocol?.myProtocolFunction(passing: "abc")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about like relationship between viewcontroller and talbleview delegate... What is differince between my example rather than being struct :/ –

Comment: no difference only you send delegate in init while in tableView you assign it , and i did that as you call delegate method while creating an object to avoid nil delegate

Answer (score 1):

Think about `protocols` as a type, in your struct you are basically saying
that this struct have a variable of this type ( your protocol )
and on `init` you are trying to call its function.

What you're missing is setting an instance of type ( your protocol )
so it can get called.

for instance :

```
MyStruct = MyStruct(myProtocol: ViewController())
```

Now your nullable protocol have a value and can call it's function in another word, protocols can't have implementation directly into them they're more like a signature contract

Read more about protocols [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create MyStruct() object out of the click action else when the scope is over your object is deinitialize.

Also, You have to call `.makeSomething()` function on the button click as the time of object creation delegate is nil.

```
var myStruct = MyStruct() // Create an instance here

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    myStruct.myProtocol = self        
// Add your action
    myStruct.makeSomething()
}
```

Comment: Is it the job of the receiver (here  `ViewController`  ) to act like the one who emits `makeSomething()` should  be triggered from Sender (here `MyStruct` )

Comment: @raja i could not understand your example.

Comment: @Sh_Khan does not make a sense for fire protocol on init. so I just fire protocol on button click.